# Український відповідник ідіоми "to take with a grain of salt"

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

"*To take with a grain of salt*" буквально перекладається як "*приймати з дрібко́м солі*" й означає "*приймати [почуте/побачене], але відноситися з підозрою*".

[Пояснюють](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21914/193496), що в англійську мову цей вираз потрапив як дослівний переклад латинського "*Cum Grano Salis*". Той в свою чергу пішов з енциклопедії «[Naturalis historia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0_%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9))» Плінія Старшого. В ній описується чудодійний рецепт протиотрути, до складу якого входить в тому числі "*дрібо́к солі*".

Чи є в українській мові питомі відповідники цього виразу?

Comment: Варіант "скептично поставитися до..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"To take with a grain of salt" в значенні "сприймати із здоровою долею скептицизму" можна перекласти за допомогою таких висловів із протилежними значеннями:

- [приймати на віру](http://sum.in.ua/s/vira) — вірити в що-небудь без доказів;
- [брати (взяти) що за чисту монету](http://sum.in.ua/s/moneta) — сприймати щось як істину,
  вважати за щиру правду.

Отже "to take with a grain of salt": "**не приймати на віру**" або "**не брати за чисту монету**".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55577/discussion-on-answer-by-miroshko----to-take-with-a).

Answer (score 6):

[Часто використовують](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9+%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9%22+OR+%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9%22) (можливо, з [російської](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust,_but_verify), але [не факт](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=laZNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9+%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B9%22)<sub>; та най і калька — чому би хороше не калькувати?</sub>):

- Довіряй, але перевіряй. 
  <sub>Варіант: Довіряй, та перевіряй.</sub>

Ще:

- Доти не звіриш, доки не зміриш.
- Більш вір своїм очам, ніж чужим речам.
  <sub>Варіанти: Вір своїм очам, а не чужим речам. Не вір чужим речам, а вір своїм очам. Не вір вухам, але очам.</sub>
- Не вір губі, положи на зуби. <sub>Я так розумію: *губа* — оповідача, а *зуби* — це про перевірку монет.</sub>
  <sub>Варіант: Губі нігди віри не май.</sub>
- Хто скоро повірить, той скоро і пропадає.
- Не всьому вір, що чуєш / що люди кажуть.
  Не всякому духу/слуху вір(уй).

В контексті грошей:

- Віра віров, а бриндзя за гроші. <sub>Орфографія передана вірно, це бойківський діалект.</sub>

Основне джерело: М. Позаяк, «Прислів'я та приказки: взаємини між людьми» (1991, Київ, «Наукова думка») (АН УРСР, Інститут мистецтвознавства, фольклору та етнографії ім. М. Т. Рильського) — там указані джерела кожної приповідки.

Answer (score 4):

**Ділити на два**

Наприклад: `Все що говорить наш сусід, потрібно ділити на два`.

**Вилами по воді писано/писане**

[Вилами по воді (писане)](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2190-vylamy-po-vodi.html) в ролі прис.– про щось малоймовірне, таке, що може й не відбутися.

**Бабка надвоє ворожила/гадала**

[Баба (бабка, бабуся) [ще] надвоє ворожила (гадала).](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/4613-2017-02-19-16-53-18.html) Невідомо, чи
здійсниться щось, чи ні.